# Nested query - Error - Too many values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to get all the values that repeat more than once in a Subquery and extract them to another query, but I cant make it work, here's my code:

```
select
 transaction_id, 
 hashed
 from  table1
 where hashed in (select hashed, count(1) 
                                        from data_headers1 
                                        where virtual_table_id = 5237260000000006162 
                                        and import_ts >= timestamp '2017-07-01 00:00:00' 
                                        group by hashed 
                                        having count(1) > 1) ;
```

Which means that I want to see every transaction_id that has 2 or more same hashed information.

Comment: `hashed` can be only compared to a single value not `hashed, count(1)` which is a tuple of 2 values. I am not well versed in *PL-SQL* so can't suggest how you can fix the sub-query part to remove `count(1)`.

Comment: Why are you including `count(1)` in the `select` clause of the subquery? You don't use it in the outer query. So delete it - the rest should work fine.

Comment: I use the count, because I want to extract all the cc values that repeat at least once, Is the only method I know for searching for a repeated value on an specific column, hence the HAVING count(1) > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the problem solved:

```
select 
 h.hashed,
 h.TRANSACTION_ID
 from table1 h inner join
 (select hashed cc, count(1) 
     from table1 where virtual_table_id = 5237260000000006162 
     and import_ts >= timestamp '2017-07-01 00:00:00' 
     group by hashed 
     having count(1) > 1) ca
  on ca.cc = h.hashed 
  where h.VIRTUAL_TABLE_ID  = 5237260000000006162;
```

It sends me the info I was looking for...

Comment: You only need a join if you must keep the `count` in the output. You are not doing that. So you don't need a join; you just need to delete `count(1)` from the `select` clause of the subquery.

Comment: But how do I only extract repetaed values of cc?

Answer (score 0):

Just segregate hashed from the output you are getting from inner query because hashed can be only compared to a single value.

```
select
transaction_id, 
hashed
from  table1
where hashed in (select hashed from(select hashed, count(1) 
                                    from data_headers1 
                                    where virtual_table_id = 5237260000000006162 
                                    and import_ts >= timestamp '2017-07-01 00:00:00' 
                                    group by hashed 
                                    having count(1) > 1));
```

This should work.

Comment: No need for yet another level of nested subquery. Just remove `count(1)` from the `select` clause of the subquery.